# Index based values pass in the terraform resource block

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform0.12+, terraform-template-file

I would like to get a index based values in the resource block values
Current  setup:

```
    locals{
       Vvn = { 
     "0" = "sam1"
      "1" = " sam2"
      "3" = "sam3"
}
```

I need to get this vvn values sam1, sam2, sam3 based on index keys in the below resource block.

```
       resource "null_resource" 
     "sample" {
           for_each = var.sampleconfig
           name = each.value.flag==true? { for n in range(length(local.vvn)): local.vvn[n]] : "string.each.value.name"
}
}
```

But it throws error and cannot able to get index based value .I don't want to pass local variables vvn to for_each since already iam using another map.
I just tried out index, lookup functions but no luck.
Expected output :

In resource block I want touse name value index based values of locals.vvn each by each.
Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To get value of a map based on index, you can use `values`. For example,

```
name = values(local.Vvn)[0]
```

But this returns values based on **exicographical order** order, not based on keys.

To use your keys, you can:

```
name = local.Vvn[0]
```

Comment: Thanks for update Marcin, but I want to get keys dynamically instead of local.Vvn[0] like explictly Passing as 0, 1,2.

Comment: @Katey Sadly its not clear what do you want to do. Your example in the question is not even valid TF code, which further complicates your question.

Comment: Thanks@Martin , it works , I just used as value itself.